# Showing error ' ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected' in this command

Tags: plsql

Here are my code.

```
Create OR Replace Procedure new_prof 
(
Pno IN VARCHAR2,
ProLast_Name IN VARCHAR2,
ProFirst_Name IN VARCHAR2,
Pro_rank IN VARCHAR2,
ProResearch_Specialty IN VARCHAR2,
Pro_DOB IN DATE,
Time_percentage DECIMAL
)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO professors VALUES(Pno,ProLast_Name,ProFirst_Name,Pro_DOB,Pro_rank,ProResearch_Specialty,Time_percentage);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Professors'||Pno||'is successfully created');

END;
/
```

When I Execute the code,

EXECUTE new_prof('P0026','Ronaldo','Christiano',TO_DATE('07/25/1978','MM/DD/YYYY'),'Senior','Programming',0.40);

After I execute this code, it show me  "the non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" at the Date there.

Comment: You are passing the values wrongly in the proc, date is the 6th param but u r passing as 4th param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing parameters in the wrong order.

To avoid problems like this, you should better pass the parameters explicitly, instead of relying on their order.

For example:

```
begin
    new_prof( Pno => 'P0026',
              ProLast_Name => 'Ronaldo',
              ProFirst_Name => 'Christiano',
              Pro_rank => 'Senior',
              ProResearch_Specialty => 'Programming',
              Pro_DOB => TO_DATE('07/25/1978','MM/DD/YYYY'),
              Time_percentage => 0.40
             );
end;
```